# Загрузка фото на сайт для мобильного

Tags: php, загрузка

Использую для загрузки фото форму `<input type='file'>` все работает хорошо, но заметил одну особенность.

Когда нажимаешь на кнопку с мобильного, предлагает выбрать откуда брать: камера, видеокамера,диктофон и документы в системном меню.

При этом, когда нажимаешь кнопку фото, допустим в вк, предлагает тоже меню, но со списком: камера, галерея и гуглфото.

Из вкладки документы тоже можно перейти в галерею, но хочется упростить жизнь пользователям)))

Как настроить это системное меню? В каком направлении рыть?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить в `accept="image/*` в `<input>`